# Optimizing query (calling subselect once)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this query:

```
 WITH b_ids as (select b_id from v where v_id = (select max(v_id) from v2)AND t = 23)
    SELECT
    case when TO_NUMBER(R_ID) IN (select * from b_ids )        
    then  'E'
        else  S
    end   S,
    case when TO_NUMBER(R_ID) IN (select * from b_ids )
        then '1000'
        else S_ID 
    end S_ID
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        S, S_ID, DECODE( Z_ID, 1, 6021, 2, 159, B_ID) R_ID
      FROM MY_TABLE
    )
```

When calling it like above my explain plan shows costs of around 0,25 million.

When I call it like below, the cost is around 1,5k:

```
SELECT
case when TO_NUMBER(R_ID) IN (1, ..., 9999)
    then  'E'
    else  S
end   S,
case when TO_NUMBER(R_ID) IN (1, ..., 9999)
    then '1000'
    else S_ID 
end S_ID
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    S, S_ID, DECODE( Z_ID, 1, 6021, 2, 159, B_ID) R_ID
  FROM MY_TABLE
)
```

Is the subselect called for each processed row?
Can I optimize this query in any way?

Comment: Why do you call it b_ids (plural)? A column called v_id in a table called v should uniquely identify a row in the table. So you are either getting the row with the maximum ID or none at all, depending on its t value. And as it's just one or zero rows, you can just outer join it to your table and use its value.

Comment: Thank you for comment. As the query is much more complex I made a mistake by simplifying it. I edited my question and now I'm getting more b_ids.